# What happens with the old view or DOM elements in the browser after a view transition?

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom

for example my gwt-app consists of two views and through the appController().goTo(place) it navigates from view1 to view2.
The ClientFactory holds the View Objects.

```
ClientFactoryImpl  implements ClientFactory{

     public View1 getView1(){
          if(view1 == null){
              view1 = new ViewImpl1();
          }
          return view1;
     }

     public View2 getView2(){
          if(view2 == null){
              view2 = new ViewImpl2();
          }
          return view2;
     }
}
```

All the dom elements of view1 are disapearing of the browser and it loads the new dom elements of view2. 
If iam now on view2 and iam pressing the back-button it will go back to view1 and view1 has the same states as before. 
My question is what happens with view1 after navigation to view2. 
What happens with all these DOM Elements of view1 like Buttons, Lists and so on. Where are they?
It says that the creation of DOM elements is expensive but when iam navigatin back to view1 the DOM elements of view1 must be rendered in to the DOM browser again or iam understanding it wrong? 
What happens in the background with all these Widgets (at the end DOM elements) after navigation and how they r coming back into to the dom after navigation back.
Where is the difference if everytime the ClientFactory would give back a new instance of the View Object?
Please help!

Sorry for my bad english, hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you keep `ViewImpl1` and `ViewImpl2` instances as lazy-initialized singletons in your `ClientFactory`, the DOM elements for each widget will be kept in memory.

Add/removing the widgets to/from another widget then attaches/detaches its DOM element to/from the parent widget's DOM element, and ultimately to the document.

If you changed your `ClientFactory` to always return a new instance, you'd always have to create the DOM elements, rather than re-use them. Depending on the complexity of the *views*, this can negatively impact your app's performances (though keeping big *views* in memory can also slow down the app by consuming too much memory, particularly on resource-constrained devices such as mobiles/tablets; it's a trade-off and you'll have to find the right balance: keep cached/in memory the *screens* that are most likely to be used next).

All the above is assuming a architecture similar to http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

Answer (score 1):

They get cached in memory and copied into the DOM when needed. When you navigate away, they simply get deleted, but the cache is still there. I just watched this on YouTube the other day. I think it was IO 10 or so... Let me go find you a link to it...

I think this is the one: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y If memory serves me right, they talked about view caching during Q&A